# Unable to login to Webpage using wget/Curl

Tags: curl, wget

I am trying to login to the webpage to get the required stats of it. The command I used is below,

> wget -v  --no-check-certificate --no-cache --keep-session-cookies --save-headers --save-cookies /dev/stdout --post-data 'username=unbt&password="xxxx"' https://ip/login.cgi

From the output, I get the html file and parsing through it, I saw,

> ```
>           <div id="errmsg" class="error">
>             ****Invalid credentials**.**
>           </div>
> ```

The same credentials works fine through browser. Is there anything wrong the way I pass the credentials?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link type="text/css" href="/150716.1130/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/150716.1130/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        //<!--
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#username").focus();
        });
        //-->
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #loginform {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #loginform table {
            margin: 0px auto;
            text-align: left;
        }

        #loginform table tr {
        }

        table.loginsubtable {
            margin: 80px auto;
        }

        table.loginsubtable td {
            padding: 0 30px 0px 30px;
        }

        table.loginsubtable img {
            border: 0px;
        }

        .loginsep {
            border-left: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
        }

        .loginsep table td {
            margin: 4px 2px 0px 2px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 5px 2px 0px 2px;
        }

        .loginsep label {
            text-align: right;
            color: white;
            font-weight: normal;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .loginsep table td.submit {
            text-align: right;
        }

        #submit {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .error {
            color: #f4324f;
            font-weight: normal;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .license {
            white-space: normal;
            text-align: justify;
            line-height: 1.8em;
            width: 250px;
        }

        .error {
            text-align: left;
            white-space: normal;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="loginsubtable">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" method="post" action="/login.cgi">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 38px"><img src="/150716.1130/images/tough-switch-pro-logo.png"></td>
    <td class="loginsep" style="padding-right: 0">
        <input type="hidden" name="uri" id="uri" value=" /" />
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="logintable" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
              <div id="errmsg" class="error">

              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Username:</label></td>
            <td align="right"><input style="width: 145px" type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
            <td align="right"><input style="width: 145px" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="8"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" height="30" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're not providing enough information to figure out how to login. what does the login page html look like? know that many websites require a cookie session and csrf token, given by doing a GET request to the login page, before allowing you to login at all

Comment: I have posted my html page.

Answer (score 0):

edit: after a teamviewer debugging session, turns out the server has a bugged implementation of `Expect: 100-continue`, and refused to log the user in, which curl used with form-data, but chrome didn't, so that header had to be disabled in curl (by setting `-H "Expect:"`)

seems the only error you're doing, is trying to login with a application/x-www-urlencoded encoded request, when the server very specifically say "use multipart/form-data encoding" (`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform"`) - unfortunately, wget does not support multipart/form-data, but curl does, so use curl maybe?

```
curl -v --insecure -F username=unbt -F password=xxxx https://ip/login.cgi
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tried curl as well. For example I used the same command you suggested below,                                                     curl -v --insecure -F username=unbt -F password=xxx https://ip/login.cgi
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>417 - Expectation Failed</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>417 - Expectation Failed</h1>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: then it probably requires you to obtain a cookie session id before logging in.. do a get request to the login page first, and use `--cookie-jar` to load & save the cookies between the 2 requests?  another possibility is that it outright blocks the curl user agent, in which you can fake it with the `--user-agent` switch

Comment: @Pradeeps no, now you're using application/x-www-urlencoded encoding again. use `-F username=unbt -F password=xxxx`, and curl will use `multipart/form-data` encoding

Comment: @Pradeeps can you provide the login url?

Comment: @Pradeeps oh, its a LAN... im bored, i got a couple of minutes, got facebook? msg https://www.facebook.com/hanshenrik.bergan or skype? msg takeoded

Comment: I got this from developer tool "https://10.9.1.3/login.cgi?uri=/". But when I looked into the page source the action field says "form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" method="post" action="/login.cgi">"

Comment: sent you req in facebook